# "Unable to connect to the remote server" when I call a rest Api

Tags: c#, api, rest-client

I am getting Unable to connect to the remote server response when I call a rest API

```
var client = new RestClient { BaseUrl = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WalletUrl"]) };
var hgh = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GetWalletRequest"];
var requests = new RestRequest(Method.POST)
{
    RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
};
requests.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
requests.AddParameter("application/json", req, ParameterType.RequestBody);
requests.AddBody(req);
var response = client.Execute(requests);
```

Comment: Are you able to open that URL with a browser or tool like curl ?

Comment: You should try to test the request using other tools (Postman). We can not help when we do not know what the URI is.